# InvalidOperationException: '#FF00AD41' is not a valid value for property 'Fill'. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF app when I try to go to the selection in Live Visual Tree it throws this exception. Weird thing is I replaced all #FF00AD41 with #00AD41 and it still threw this exception.

Here's a piece of code where that Fill value is used:

```
<Canvas x:Key="IconStartExportThumb"
        Width="17.458"
        Height="56.000"
        x:Shared="False">
    <Path Data="F1 M 13.000,26.021 C 13.000,29.611 10.089,32.521 6.500,32.521 C 2.910,32.521 0.000,29.611 0.000,26.021 C 0.000,22.431 2.910,19.521 6.500,19.521 C 10.089,19.521 13.000,22.431 13.000,26.021 Z" Fill="#ffa9e1bf" />
    <Path Data="F1 M 10.000,26.021 C 10.000,27.954 8.433,29.521 6.500,29.521 C 4.567,29.521 3.000,27.954 3.000,26.021 C 3.000,24.088 4.567,22.521 6.500,22.521 C 8.433,22.521 10.000,24.088 10.000,26.021 Z" Fill="#ff00ad41" />
    <Path Data="F1 M 5.458,0.000 L 5.458,56.000 L 7.458,56.000 L 7.458,2.000 L 17.458,2.000 L 17.458,0.000 L 5.458,0.000 Z" Fill="#ff00ad41" />
</Canvas>
```

For this exception I cannot even debug using live visual tree. Any advice is appreciated.

[image: the exception]

Comment: do you have this issue when running app without Live Visual Tree? Brush has associated type converter which is able to create SolidColorBrush from rgb hex code

Comment: @ASh nope, only when I Select a control from the LVT. The app seems to run fine otherwise.

Comment: Odd thing is; I just copy past your code, without `key` and `shared` and the LVT works fine.

Comment: This IS weird. I still get this exception but by some miracle at least now I can see the properties of a control.